# .htacces url_rewrite difficulties

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with the configuration of the `.htaccess` of small website that I'm working on.

I want all pages to be redirected to `index.php?page=REQUEST` and that file will find in the database the content for the requested page.

The problem occurs when I have installed a forum, so I want these forum pages to redirect to the `index.php?page=forum&params`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*).html

RewriteRule ^(.*)forum/category/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=forum&lang=$1&category=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(\.html?)$ index\.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html?)$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Evetything works fine, except the forum part. How do I need to change the `.htacces`?

Comment: you'd have to show exactly what a forum url looks like. we can't fix if we can't see what the inputs are.

Comment: for example this url: www.url.com/en/forum/category/1

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|gif|svg|css|js)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/forum/topic/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=forum&lang=$1&topic=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/forum/category/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=forum&lang=$1&category=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(\.html?)$ index\.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html?)$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that your `RewriteCond` is matching requests that end in `.html`. As your forum URLs don't end in `.html` the condition for the subsequent RewriteRule is never met.

There are some other possible problems too:

- `^(.*)forum` will match `www.url.com/en/` when it looks like you probably just want `en`
- `category/(.*)` will match any characters, including forward slashes and the like. Presumably you just want it to match a decimal identifier.
- Links to things that aren't covered by your rewrite config e.g. images

I'd probably rewrite your config to look something like this (N.B. not tested in Apache; only in a regex debugger):

```
RewriteEngine on    

# only match forum URLs
# e.g                url.com/en/forum/category/12345
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+/forum/category/[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/forum/category/([0-9]+) index.php?page=forum&lang=$1&category=$2 [L]

# match all URLs ending in .html
# e.g.            url.com/en/foo.html
# and                url.com/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+\.html$

# a bit complicated, this matches both
#                      /apage.html
#               /folder/apage.html
RewriteRule ^(?:/(.+))?/(.+)\.html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

The second RewriteRule should always provide a value for `page` but only provide a value for `lang` if the URL is of the form /lang/page.html. This should be OK if your index.php file can accept an empty `lang` parameter or supply a default value.

Alternatively, if you don't mind keeping your existing regex and it's only images, CSS etc you want to bypass in URL rewriting you can add some rules at the start to skip them e.g.

```
RewriteEngine on    

# don't actually rewrite, and stop processing rules
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|css|js)$ - [L]

# only match forum URLs
# e.g                url.com/en/forum/category/12345
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+/forum/category/[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/forum/category/([0-9]+) index.php?page=forum&lang=$1&category=$2 [L]

etc...
```

Comment: thanks hilsy, i have removed it and now it is better, but now i dont see the images on the website. Why is that ?

Comment: I updated my answer to account for that, and also added how I'd probably (re)write the regex to be a bit shorter and clearer.

Comment: Hi hillsy, unfortunately your suggestion for the config doesnt work for me. Your first answer + the addition for the images works, except when i am on the forum pages (f.e. url.com/en/forum/category/1 ) than it does not display the images. Please note that i use relative path to the images.

Comment: here is how the .htacces file looks like now:

Comment: RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|gif|svg|css|js)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/forum/topic/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=forum&lang=$1&topic=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/forum/category/(.*)?$ index\.php?page=forum&lang=$1&category=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(\.html?)$ index\.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html?)$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: By "relative" do you mean something like ../../images/foo.png, so an image linked from url.com/en/forum/category/1 would be requested from url.com/en/forum/images/foo.png?

Comment: yes, the images have paths like this ../../images/foo.png